# Unlocking a LUKS encrypted root partition remotely via SSH

Tags: centos

My server is running CentOS 6.4, fully encrypted using LUKS.

The question is. What can I do to be able to insert the passphrase after a server reboot, thru ssh?

The only referente I found, was about installing dropbear and busybox, and editing the file initramfs.

---

But I cound't find any initramfs on CenOS. busybox is already installed, I was able to install dropbear thru rpm.

So, is there an equivalent to initramfs in CentOS?

Answer (score 0):

It's called initrd, not initramfs there.

See http://www.centos.org/docs/2/rhl-cg-en-7.2/buildkernel-initrd.html
http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/CreateNewInitrd